# FSEvent failed to create stream in root context: Error: FSEventStreamCreate: _FSEventStreamCreate: ERROR: watch_path() failed for

Tags: c++, c, macos, cocoa, fsevents

I want to monitor directories on mac using FSEvent.

This Error is getting generated in root context. If i run program in user context it work properly.

**Error is:** FSEventStreamCreate: _FSEventStreamCreate: ERROR: watch_path() failed for some_path.

I want to watch array of paths.
but creating stream get failed.

its working fine for lower number of paths in root.

code I use to create stream is.

```
    FSEventStreamContext * streamContext = (FSEventStreamContext *)malloc(sizeof(FSEventStreamContext));
    streamContext->version = 0;
    streamContext->info = NULL;//&fileDescriptor;
    streamContext->retain = NULL;
    streamContext->release = NULL;
    streamContext->copyDescription = NULL;

    /* Create the stream, passing in a callback */
    stream = FSEventStreamCreate(
                                 NULL,
                                 &myCallbackFunction,
                                 streamContext,
                                 pathsToWatch,  /* This is the array of paths I am passing to watch, It work fine in user context for large number of objects too. */
                                 kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, /* Or a previous event ID */
                                 latency,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot /* Flags explained in reference */
                                 );

 if (NULL == stream) /* Stream get NULL */
    {
        NSLog(@"Ruturning False : stream == NULL");
        NSLog(@"FSEventStreamCreate  failed");
        return;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about running it in root context watching for root directory "/"?

Comment: I want to run code in launch demon, due to that i want it work in root user context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot` flag in function `FSEventStreamCreate()` cause problem, I don't know why.

But when I remove that flag it run in root context and user context also for many number of paths.